# How do I get term data associated with the current post, where the result is not wrapped in HTML?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'd like to get term data from a custom taxonomy associated with the current post.

I can do this with `get_the_term_list($id $custom_taxonomy)`.
However, this returns the data I want wrapped in HTML.

I'd like to get the data but not wrapped in HTML.

I presume this means using a function that returns an object, and from that point I'd work with the object. `get_terms` looks like a likely candidate. But I haven't been able to craft the parameters correctly.

How exactly can I get the data I want?

Comment: [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so let's make it straight:

[get_the_term_list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

> Returns an HTML string of taxonomy terms associated with a post and
>   given taxonomy. Terms are linked to their respective term listing
>   pages.

So it will generate HTML code and return it as string.

[get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

> Retrieves the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies.

So it has nothing to do with current post.

[get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)

> Retrieve the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post.

So this is the one you're looking for, I guess.

It will get the terms of given taxonomy that are assigned to given post and return them as array - so you can iterate it and do whatever you want with them...

Comment: This cleared things up nicely and gave me a path to a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @bob No problem :)